# Is there an alternative to Everyquest?

Tags: mods, world-of-warcraft

I liked to use the AddOn Everyquest pre-4.0.3a to be able to complete all quests. It was simply a list which showed you all quests you have not yet completed - grouped by zone.

However, the AddOn was not updated with 4.0.3a and therefore became useless. Are there any alternatives to Everyquest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WoWhead](http://www.wowhead.com) introduced a pretty amazing new feature based on some new API goodies in 4.0.3. Specifically, they introduced what they're referring to as [Personalized Search](http://www.wowhead.com/blog=174816/personalized-search-update-now-works-on-all-completion-data).

You'll need to run the [WoWhead client addon](http://www.wowhead.com/client), and then upload your data to them after a session, but once you've done so, you'll be able to search and filter quests, mounts, recipes, achievements, pets, titles and more based on what you've completed, and what you haven't. Just log in to WoWhead, and set a default character, and it will automatically filter by any informaiton needed.

[image: WoWhead screenshot]

> The real power of this comes when you view a list of quests for a zone, then you filter for ones that are 'available' and for your faction. This will give you a list of quests you can accept immediately, and hopefully will get you well on your way to Realm First once Cataclysm launches. Don't forget, though, this works for all data types that show up in the Profiler, including mounts, companions, recipes, quests, achievements, titles, and actions.

Comment: Problem with this is that it does not updatae itself while playing.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Carbonite](http://carboniteaddon.com/), it includes a quest database that lists all the quests not completed in the current zone (or all zones if you like, change level brackets and other things), including quests that start in other zones.  You can even select them and choose waypoint to quest giver and it'll give you the route you need to take to get there, whereever it is.

Admittedly there's a little more to Carbonite than EveryQuest, but it's what I use.

EDIT:

Another alternative (<del>which I hadn't realised had been updated</del> actually on closer inspection its not even the addon I thought it was, but it does what it says on the tin, so...) is [Quest Completist](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/quest_completist.aspx).  I haven't tried it, but it looks like it has the same functionality and is also up to date with 4.0.3a.

Comment: I think that Carbonite is too much over kill to have such a simple feature as Everyquest provided.

Comment: Quest Completist doesn't seem to be very complete

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the Loremaster achievement, there's an addon called Loremaster specifically for this purpose.